# Derivative function of $ \sqrt[5]{4x^{8}} $

Tags: derivatives

I can't manage to simplify the function further. How can I further simplify $g(x)$:

$g(x)$ is how far I've got and $f'(x)$ is the final solution.
[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what it is you're trying to do *and show what you have tried already?* Are you trying to use algebra to transform $g(x)$ into $f'(x)$?

Comment: Please have a look at [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) about asking a good question on this site. As it stands, this post is going to be downvoted and closed.

Comment: You'd probably help yourself better if you could explain your reasoning each step, what you have learned and what rules are you using.

Comment: @SammyBlack
I'm trying to derive $ \sqrt[5]{4x^{8}} $ with the chain rule as we've learned in school. The problem is that I need to simplify it and I don't know how to proceed. Here's what I've done:

So first off, $ \sqrt[5]{4x^{8}} $ can be written as $(4x^8)^{\frac {1}{5}}$
Then with the chain rule "if $f(x) = u(v(x))$ then $f'(x) = u'(v(x)) * v'(x)$", and the power rule "if $f(x) = x^n$ then $f'(x) = n * x^{n-1}$, we can derive the function:
$f'(x)$ must be $\frac {1}{5} * (4x^8)^{\frac {-4}{5}} * 32x^7$
But I don't know how to simplify this...

Comment: @SammyBlack I simply don't know how to simplify the g(x) function on the image. I don't know why context or whatever is needed here

Comment: It looks like there's a good answer below. In the future all of this motivation and the various calculations here in the comments should be included in the original post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you already have a correct answer, and may not need to simplify any further. But if you would like to show that it can be simplified to your stated $g(x)$, it can be done. To start, I think our main goal is to get the $4x^8$ out from the bottom of the fraction so it can match what $g(x)$ looks like. So, step by step,
$$32 \frac{x^7}{5(4x^8)^{4/5}}$$
$$=32 \frac{x^7}{5(4x^8)^{4/5}} \frac{x}{x}$$
$$=8 \frac{4x^8}{5x (4x^8)^{4/5}} $$
$$=8 \frac{(4x^8)^{1/5}}{5x} $$
$$=8 \frac{\sqrt[5]{(4x^8)}}{5x} $$

Let me know if there are any steps that need clarification or explanation.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you very much!